# setInterval variable not accessable

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
var cnt1 = 0;
function initOctoView(){
   var newcnt1 = printAdsBox1(cnt1, imgPerBox1); // first time on first load
   var totalBoxes8 = setInterval(function() {
      newcnt1 = printAdsBox1(newcnt1, imgPerBox1); // all 5 sec
   }, 5000);
}
```

This function get called by this:

```
if($('.octoView').length > 0){
    initOctoView();
}
```

And works fine so far.

Later on I have:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.windowXL', function () {
   window.clearInterval(totalBoxes8);
}
```

But this returns that totalBoxes8 is not defined.
What is my mistake? Please advice!

Comment: Your calling totalBoxes8 outside of its scope.

Comment: Exactly what @adamb said. Out of scope. You gotta put it out of the function.

Comment: Hi again, OK I got the issue with the scope. But even I declare it as gloabl, it's still not working...
Some more details: I am calling the initOctoView(); from my index and I am loading a another page into an iframe. Within this iframe I have the button a.windowXL calling the function which should do the clearInterval. Can this be an issue between the 2 "frames" I am using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare totalBoxes8 with var inside function - totalBoxes8 is local variable accesable in this function only. You may make it global:

```
var cnt1 = 0;
var totalBoxes8;
function initOctoView(){
     var newcnt1 = printAdsBox1(cnt1, imgPerBox1); // first time on first load
     totalBoxes8 = setInterval(function() {
          newcnt1 = printAdsBox1(newcnt1, imgPerBox1); // all 5 sec
      }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$(function(){

    var cnt1 = 0, totalBoxes8 ;
    function initOctoView(){
       var newcnt1 = printAdsBox1(cnt1, imgPerBox1); // first time on first load
       totalBoxes8 = setInterval(function() {
          newcnt1 = printAdsBox1(newcnt1, imgPerBox1); // all 5 sec
       }, 5000);
    }

   $(document).on('click', 'a.windowXL', function () {
      window.clearInterval(totalBoxes8);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`totalBoxes8` is `undefined` because it is declared *locally* within the scope of the function `initCotoView()`, and is thus unavailable to the *global* scope

you can  declare a global from *within* the function by explicitly attaching it to the global `window` object. Something like:

```
function foo() {
  window.myVar = 1; // declares a global
} 

foo(); // call the function to actually make the declaration

console.log(window.myVar); // the variable is accessible globally
```